# ¿Como conseguir dos dígitos en una consulta de un valor numérico?

Tags: sql, sql-server

He intentado el siguiente `SELECT`:

```
SELECT (2*3) as Resultado
```

He obtenido esto

```
Resultado 
6
```

Necesito este resultado:

```
Resultado
06
```

Si multiplico así:

```
SELECT (12*2)

Resultado 
24
```

Quiero que el resultado solo contenga dos dígitos siempre ¿como se hace eso?

Comment: ¿Que pasa si el resultado de por si tiene mas de dos dígitos?¿Esta validado para esos casos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`06` no existe como número, por lo que para obtener tu resultado lo que necesitas es primero convertirlo a un string. Una forma sencilla sería la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @Num int = 3;
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),@Num*2),2)
```

Ahora, debes considerar que si el resultado de la multiplicación es `100`, por ejemplo, entonces vas a obtener `'00'` (o `'0*'`) como resultado

Comment: se podria meter un case num<10 , case betwen 0 10, o format(number,'00')

Comment: @aloMalbarez `FORMAT` es para SQL Server 2012 en adelante (el op no especifica su versión), por lo que preferí escribir código que funciona para versiones anteriores también

Comment: por eso primero sugería ampliar la respuesta con el case between

Answer (score 2):

Existen las funciones LPAD y RPAD que rellenan una cadena con el carácter que le especifiques hasta que llegue a la longitud deseada (LPAD lo hace por la izquierda y RPAD por la derecha:

LPAD(*cadena_a_modificar*,*longitud_deseada*,*caracter_de_relleno*)

En tu caso:

**SELECT LPAD(2*3,2,0) as Resultado**

Esto nos dará que Resultado es 06

Desconozco si en tu plataforma existen estas funciones o algo similar. Tendrás que probar.

Answer (score 1):

Una respuesta similar a la del buen hermano [Lamak](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/26/lamak)

```
DECLARE @numero INT, 
        @formato VARCHAR(10),
        @expresion VARCHAR(10)

SET @formato = '00'
SET @numero = (2*3)
SET @expresion = RIGHT( @formato + CAST(@numero AS varchar), 2)

SELECT @expresion AS RESULTADO
```

Esto genera:

```
RESULTADO
06
```

Referencia: http://devjoker.com/contenidos/articulos/358/Formatear-numeros-en-SQL-Server.aspx